# How to detect and remove recursive structure in hierarchical data in R?

Tags: r, data.tree

here is an example data like mine. Think of it as a dataset of user activity on a website.

| time | from | to |
| --- | --- | --- |
| t0 | A | a |
| t1 | a | b |
| t2 | a | c |
| t3 | a | d |
| t4 | b | x1 |
| t5 | b | x2 |
| t6 | c | y1 |
| t7 | x1 | a |

I want to generate hierarchical data. But like last row in dataset, there is infinite loop.

Parent is a then child is b.

Parent is b then child is x1.

Parent is x1 then child is a again. So here there is an infinite loop. So I can't use my original data because of that.

So my question is, how can i remove rows like the end?

Thank you.

I've tried to write some loop functions. But i couldn't.

PS: Edit example data

Comment: One strategy for recognizing an infinite loop is to look for the new node in the list of nodes already handled.   But without seeing your existing code, I can't tell you how to add this test.

Comment: I m not actually that good at nodes. Still learning. But i've tried code like that: (data.tree library)

`test=data.table(Parent = c('A','a','a','a','b','b','c','x1'),
           Child = c('a','b','c','d','x1','x2','y1', 'a'))
data.tree::FromDataFrameNetwork(test)`
and I've got error for this code. Error is: "Error: C stack usage  7955072 is too close to the limit". I think this error occurs due to loop @user2554330

Comment: That error is typically a sign of an infinite recursion, e.g. `f <- function() f()` (but usually more complicated).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data frame can be thought of as representing the edgelist of a [directed graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph). The rows you describe as causing an 'infinite loop' are called the [feedback arc set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedback_arc_set), and the operation of removing these rows leaves the *maximal acyclic subgraph* of your graph, which is what you are looking for.

Using the `igraph` package, you can explicitly turn your data frame into a graph, find the edge(s) that cause an infinite loop using `feedback_arc_set`, subtract these from your graph, then convert the resulting directed acyclic graph back into a data frame:

```r
library(igraph)

g <- graph_from_data_frame(df[c(2:3, 1)])
g <- g - feedback_arc_set(g)
new_df <- igraph::as_data_frame(g)[c(3, 1:2)]

new_df
#>   time from to
#> 1   t0    A  a
#> 2   t1    a  b
#> 3   t2    a  c
#> 4   t3    a  d
#> 5   t4    b x1
#> 6   t5    b x2
#> 7   t6    c y1
```

Note that this has correctly identified time `t7` as the row causing a feedback arc and removed it from your data frame.

---

**Data in reproducible format**

```r
df <- structure(list(time = c("t0", "t1", "t2", "t3", "t4", "t5", "t6", 
"t7"), from = c("A", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "x1"), to = c("a", 
"b", "c", "d", "x1", "x2", "y1", "a")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: Wow! This is a very clever answer!